# Typescript IDE Auto imports from dist not src

Tags: typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, webstorm, yarnpkg

I'm currently working on a project that is a Typescript Monorepo.

The folder structure looks something like this:

```
Clients
├- tsconfig.json
└- Packages
   ├- Core
   | ├- tsconfig.json
   | ├-┬ src
   | | └- MyModule.ts
   | └-┬ dist
   |   ├- MyModule.js
   |   └- MyModule.d.ts
   └┬ Web
    ├- tsconfig.json
    └-┬ src
      └- WebComponent.tsx
```

`core/src` contains my module where `core/dist` contains my build.
When I auto-import a module on `web/src/WebComponent.tsx` it auto-imports as `@myApp/dist/MyModule` instead of `@myApp/src/MyModule`.

This is what my TSConfig paths look like (in the root folder):

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
    "@myApp/core/src/*": ["./packages/core/src/*"],
 }
```

I also tried this:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
    "@myApp/core/*": ["./packages/core/*"],
}
```

This doesn't seem to be an IDE Issue as we have people on the team working with both VSCode and Webstorm, both groups of users experience this bug.

**EDIT:**
If you are also experiencing this issue I have written a [temporary fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66003117/3673022) however a proper solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem with Webstorm, it feels like a Typescript issue perhaps? I'll start a bounty since it's becoming very annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure this will fully resolve your issue, but I will leave it here nonetheless. I am only able to reproduce the issue on Webstorm, and not Visual Studio Code. If this does not resolve your issue, leave a comment and I will investigate further.

#### TypeScript Configuration: `tsconfig.json`

You can try modifying your `tsconfig.json`s to explicitly exclude the `dist` folder using the `exclude` flag (on the same JSON level as `include`), documented under [TypeScript's TSConfig Reference documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude).

Adding the following configuration entry

```
   "exclude": ["dist/**/*"]
```

should indicate the directory should not be imported from in IDEs. However, this
seems to work on Visual Studio Code, but is not respected by Webstorm (addressed in the following section). I am not 100% sure why Visual Studio Code is deciding to try and import files outside of files mentioned in `includes`. If this is not working for you on Visual Studio Code, I will need more details to make a reproduction.

#### WebStorm (or any other JetBrains IDE)

There are two solutions:

- Project-specific: On any JetBrains IDE, you can mark a directory as "excluded" (e.g. `dist` directory) by opening the context-menu (right clicking, by default) and clicking `Mark Directory as | Excluded`.
- Globally: Under `File | Settings | Editor | File Types`, you can add another entry under `Ignore Files and Folders` for `dist`.

> Note: This will prevent the IDE from displaying any "sources" from the excluded directory (e.g. `dist`) as a suggestion. If the identifier is unambiguous, it will correctly import it without a further prompt.

Unfortunately, this appears to require manual interaction from a developer after initializing the project - I was unable to find if you could specify an exclusion rule within a VCS repository and have the settings automatically applied when initializing the project in the IDE.

Comment: Just tried both of these solutions and neither seemed to work... I did find it strange though that editing the pathname in tsconfig didn't seem to change the pathname in the import popup. I've got 0 ideas for this one. Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: @pfych is it possible you could give me enough details to create a minimal reproduction in either IDE? VS Version, any plugins, sample repo? I use WebStorm significantly and have never had an issue using excludes on the `dist` folder, but I have not used Visual Studio Code enough to experience the interaction.

Answer (score 3):

The solution we ended up coming too was to write an ESLint rule which highlights the `dist` import and replaces it with `src` on an `eslint --fix` command.

Here is what we did

**Structure:**

```
Clients
├- tsconfig.json
├- .eslintrc.js (UPDATED!)
├- package.json (UPDATED!)
├- eslint (NEW!)
|  ├- index.js (NEW!)
|  └- package.json (NEW!)
└- Packages
   ├- Core
   | ├- tsconfig.json
   | ├-┬ src
   | | └- MyModule.ts
   | └-┬ dist
   |   ├- MyModule.js
   |   └- MyModule.d.ts
   └┬ Web
    ├- tsconfig.json
    └-┬ src
      └- WebComponent.tsx
```

**eslint/package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "eslint-plugin-myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

**eslint/index.js**:
This custom rule parses imports and replaces `dist` with `src` if it matches a patern

```js
module.exports.rules = {
  'no-dist-imports': (context) => ({
    ImportDeclaration: (node) => {
      const path = node.source.raw.toString();
      if (path.includes('@myApp/core/dist')) {
        const fixedImport = node.source.raw.replace('dist', 'src');
        context.report({
          node: node.source,
          message: `Importing from dist`,
          fix(fixer) {
            return fixer.replaceText(node.source, fixedImport);
          },
        });
      }
    },
  }),
};
```

**.eslintrc.js** (Added the following)

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'myApp',
  ],
  rules: {
    'myApp/no-dist-imports': 'error',
  },
};
```

**package.json** (Added the following)

```json
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "devDependencies": {
      "eslint-plugin-myApp": "file:./eslint",
  }
}
```

It's not the perfect solution however it works for the team. If any dist imports somehow make it past the IDE's lint on save feature we have a script lint before push. dist imports no longer make it into our PR's.

If there is a better solution (That fixes the imports preferably :P) please let us know!

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me in intellij

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the same issue and solved it with a different chnage:

The `package.json` had `"main"`, `"types"`, and `"files"` properties like this:

```json
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.js",
  "files": ["dist"],
}
```

The final thing that I add to make it work was defining the `"typings"` property:

```json
  "typings": "dist/index",
```

With this change; the IDE's I tried started to import from the package again instead of `package/dist` path.

Comment: "typings" is synonymous with "types". The reason it worked is that you had "types" as `"dist/index.d.js"` instead of `"dist/index.d.ts"`.